# How to create extension UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate or fix overlapping view SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, view, uitapgesturerecognizer

I create this basic tap gesture function for dismissing view and I added a delegate to override tap when the user taps on another custom sheet (container).

```
@objc func handleTapGesture() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func tapGestureToDissmis() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture))
    tap.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
} 

extension TextConfigurationVC : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    
    if touch.view?.isDescendant(of: container) == true {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

My problem is that I want to implement this for 8 screens and I don't want to repeat my self. i create in my UIViewcontroler extension file this tap function and I don't now how to pass this view :

```
extension UIViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view?.isDescendant(of: **<UIView>)** == true {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

when I created the global container, each time it was called, it was overlapping each other
(tap x 6)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it self.view or simply view (= view controller view you want to dismiss ? In other case you could create a custom II view controller with a default viewDidLoad to initialise the dismiss tap gesture

Comment: Another way is to add a (computed) var in your extension to store the view.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to handle individual tap action for views

```
   extension UIView {
private struct OnClickHolder {
    static var _closure:()->() = {}
}

private var onClickClosure: () -> () {
    get { return OnClickHolder._closure }
    set { OnClickHolder._closure = newValue }
}

func onTap(closure: @escaping ()->()) {
    self.onClickClosure = closure
    
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onClickAction))
    addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc private func onClickAction() {
    onClickClosure()
}
}
```

Usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let view = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 50))
view.backgroundColor  = .red
view.onTap {
    print("View Tapped")
}
```

}